# Matching 3-4 digit multiples of 10

Tags: regex

I'm trying and struggling to match 3-4 digit multiples of 10, up to a maximum of 1390. Numbers below 100 begin with a 0.

Example Matches:

```
010
200
380
1280
1390
```

Example Non Matches:

```
0200
285 
231
1400
```

My current closest pattern is: `([1-9]|0){1}[0-9]{1,2}0`, however it's not matching numbers such as 1130.

How would I modify this pattern to fit my needs or is there another pattern I should use?

Comment: Why doesn't `0200` and `1400`  match?

Comment: @FelixCastor 0200 is over 100 and shouldn't have a leading 0 and 1400 is over 1390.

Comment: You might try [`^(?:[0-9]{2}0|1[0-2][0-9]0|13[0-9]0)$`](https://regex101.com/r/KUoiDm/1).

Comment: Do people still not know about http://regex101.com, http://regexr.com/, https://regexone.com/, etc.? It would really behoove you to know how to create regexes yourself, rather than coming to SO every time you want someone to make one for you...

Comment: But if people do that, What will Wiktor Stribiżew  do of this life ? (just kidding :p)

Comment: @baddger964: I would use another way to solve this issue.

Comment: Should it also match `000`? Is that considered a 3-digit multiple of 10?

Comment: what's `([1-9]|0)` different from `[0-9]`?

Comment: @FelixCastor I suppose 0200 could match and I just strip the leading 0

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've been tapping about on regexstorm.net for a few hours now. That's how I came up with my current pattern string.

Comment: @tobias_k no, not 000

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc come to think of it, there is no difference. I'm just not very good at all at regular expressions so it was one of the things I tried.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you don't mind me asking, how would you go about this? This is for input validation

Comment: In C#, you may use string and Math methods for that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I suppose I could. I'll have a think. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others in the comments have mentioned, regular expressions are not the best tool for this job. That said, there might be situations where you don't have another choice, so let's proceed.

We have a hard problem, so we'll try to split it into easier problems. We can partition the set of possible numbers as follows, so that the individual regexs become glaringly obvious:

- `000-990`: That's `^[0-9][0-9]0$`.
- `1000-1390`: That's `^1[0-3][0-9]0$`.

Now all we need to do is combine those two. We note that both have a common prefix of `^` and a common suffix of `[0-9]0$`, so we can simplify it to:

```
^([0-9]|1[0-3])[0-9]0$
```

In fact, you might make life easier for the poor soul who will have to maintain your regex in a few years (might be you) and keep it in its simple form, with a few added comments (requires the "ignore whitespace" option):

```
^( (?# 000, 010, ..., 990)     [0-9][0-9]0
  |(?# 1000, 1010, ..., 1390) 1[0-3][0-9]0
 )$
```

This is under the assumption that `000` should also be valid. If it shouldn't, you can apply the same technique and partition your numbers into `010-090`, `100-990` and `1000-1390`. Doing that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Should it also match `000`? Because this one does.

Comment: @tobias_k: Good question. I'd say it should (unless stated otherwise), since, mathematically, 0 is considered to be a multiple of every integer. I've mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match values excluding 000, here is regex:

- 010-990: That's `^(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])0$`